# Dynamic async custom select component and Vue.js2

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have that pice of code:

```
<service-type-select v-model="form.service_type_id.value"></service-type-select>
```

and my custom component:

```
<template>
    <select @change="change" name="filter_service_type_id_eq">
        <option value="">Example</option>
        <option v-for="service_type in service_types" :value="service_type.id">
            {{ service_type.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                service_types: [],
                url: '/servicetypes'
            }
        },
        model: {
            prop: 'value',
            event: 'change'
        },
        props: [ 'value' ],
        mounted() {
            this.setServiceTypes(this.url);
        },
        methods: {
            setServiceTypes: function(url) {
                axios.get(url).then(response => {
                    this.service_types = JSON.parse(response.data.content);
                });
            },
            change: function(event) {
                const select = event.target;
                this.$emit('change', select.options[select.selectedIndex].value);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I was reading documentation: [vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events) I thought I can use `v-model` on `select` with `change` because this `root` should call `@change` event. That simple example from doc doesn't work in my case or I'm doing something wrong. I must call `@change` event not automatically what is not what I need. Someone can explain it?

Comment: Your code appears to work? http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/zZWzbJ?editors=1010

Comment: Yes, my code work and call proper event but, it should not be automatically without my `@change` with emit event?
And if you set `service` as 1 in app, select will not select proper options, this need next another function...

Comment: In every case that I have seen, you have to emit the event yourself, you can't rely on the native event generated by the element rendered inside your component. Same thing even with `input`.

Comment: So, if it's only and proper way, I will do it like above. Thanks.